# How to set the hint for spinner in Android

Tags: android, spinner

I want to set the hint in spinner. Like in edit text, I am giving the hint, that is:

```
android:Hint="First Name"
```

So what should I do for Spinner like for state?

My state will dynamically fill from the database. If I give the hint in array `index[0]`, then it will effect on zeroth position of that field.

How can I do it?

**Code**

```
public String[] getState()
{
    try
    {
       Cursor cursor = dbUser.State();
       if (cursor.getCount() >= 0)
       {
           array_state = new String[cursor.getCount()];
           i = 0;
           while (cursor.moveToNext())
           {
              array_state[i] = cursor.getString(1);
              i++;
           }
        }
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     { 
         // TODO: handle exception
     }
     return array_state;
 }
```

Comment: No...How Toast message..I want to show it into the spinner that hint is what should you fill here..like if state is there..then.like this type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is when you implement `onSelectionListener` of `Spinner` just neglect the `zeroth` position and display your hint at `zeroth` position

**Update**

change your code to this

```
array_state = new String[cursor.getCount() + 1];
array_state[0] = "Hint String";
i = 1;
```

Comment: Yaa I have done this also but it will not happen.bcoz it will effect on first value.

Comment: post your code then might be you are doing it wrong way

Comment: ok I am sending it u u wait..

Comment: hey thanks for help it is working but when I click on submit button then I have given the validation that all fields are required.and if somebody not selected the state then by default it will save "state" that is not correct.

Comment: so plz give me the solution for this also..hint is coming from ur code..but

Comment: Then do manual coding check if the spinner text is your hint string then alert user to enter one

Comment: it will save index of zeroth position in array_state[].so hint will save as a state.I want that when i click on spinner the only it will show the data

Answer (score 4):

Use `android:prompt="select your fruit"` attribute for the `<Spinner>`.

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> ad_state  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,array_state);
        ad_state.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        state.setAdapter(ad_state);

Comment: private String array_state[]; this is the way to initlize

Comment: public String[] getState() {
  try {

   Cursor cursor = dbUser.State();
   if (cursor.getCount() >= 0) {
    array_state = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    i = 0;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
     array_state[i] = cursor.getString(1);
     i++;
    }

   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
  }
  return array_state;
 }

Comment: and this is the method to fill spinner from the database at runtime..

Comment: What is this? My dear update your question with this code actually.

Comment: That will display on the Dialog as Title where the Spinner items are being shown not as hint

Comment: @PareshMayani please see the above comment. It cannot be shown as a hint...

Comment: The android:prompt does not take string values.